# Customizing Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

I have a database with a table :

```
User { UserId, Name, Number, DateCreated, DateEffective, DateEnd, DateReplaced }
```

I expose the information in the database containing the table through WCF Data Services.

1) the columns : DateCreated, DateEffective, DateEnd, DateReplaced are for keeping historical records and as such should not appear to the clients using my WCF Data Service.

2) also, Whenever a client makes the query :

```
         var q = from u in service.Users select u;
```

I want it to return only the users who have the DateEnd column set to null.

Is there any way to achieve that functionality ?

Comment: I think the syntax is something like: foreach(var q in service.Users.Where((q => q.DateEnd == null)))

Comment: I don't want the client to see the DateEnd column. I want those columns to be masked from them.

Comment: I was trying to help you with 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 If you're going through WCF you're serializing to XML, right? So mark the properties that you don't want to be serialized as NonSerialized.

```
[NonSerialized()] public string test; [MSDN NonSerializedAttribute Class][1]
```

2 You'll have to expose a method for the client to access that has already filtered the null DateEnd columns out.

Such as

```
public class Service{
private List<User> _users;
public List<User> Users {
    get{
        from u in _users where u.DateEnd == null select u
    }
}
...
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The User class will still have the field DateEnd visible at the client's end.

Comment: You mean that if you do it my way, the property will still exist on the other side and that you don't want that? If this is the case, then make another class that doesn't have the properties that you want to hide, and box the User class into the SpecialUser class and you're done.